# Add one column dor each value in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of random numbers between 0 and 40, generated by:

```
A=[]
x=0

while x<100:  
    a=random.randint(0,40)
    A.append(a)
    x+=1
```

Given an already existing DataFrame with 1 column of seconds (86400 rows), how can I add 1 column per each value in the list A?

To explain it better: I would like add to the dataframe 100 columns, each one with the first row containing the value in the list A. Then, in the next rows I will do other calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with new one row DataFrame with `index=[0]`, so after join with existing DataFrame with default index it align data to first row with same index - `0`:

```
#existing df
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.arange(86400)})
#print (df1.head())

#100 columns df
df2 = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(0, 40, 100)])
#if want create df by list A
#df2 = pd.DataFrame([A])
#print (df2)

#join together
df = df1.join(df2)
#print (df.head())
```